# R - Help to build time column from 0?

Tags: r

I need to create a 'time' column, starting at 0 and adding increments of 0.0005. The length of the column should be dependent on the length of existing columns. What I have tried at so far is below.

So in my head, the below script says: create a column with 0 and 0.0005 as data points 1 and 2, cumulatively add the difference between data points 1 and 2 and repeat for length of specified column. This doesn't really work, hence why I am posting here. If anyone has some sage advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
df$time = c(0,0.0005, cumsum(diff(df$time [1:2], lag = 1)), length(df$other.column))
```

Expected outcome

```
time
0
0.0005
0.001
0.0015
0.002
0.0025
0.003
0.0035
0.004
0.0045
0.005
0.0055
0.006
0.0065
0.007
0.0075
0.008
0.0085
0.009
0.0095
etc
```

Comment: Please show your input example

Comment: As in the example of what I tried previously? Have included that above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can multiply the `0.00005` with the sequence of rows

```
df$time <- (seq_len(nrow(df)) - 1) * 0.0005
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
```

Comment: Have just tried 'df$time = seq(0, length.out = df$other.column, 0.0005)' and i get 0 for all data points.      Sorry for all the comment and deletes, I don't know how to get code here properly

Comment: No insult at all intended. Very new to stack overflow and still figuring out how to work this

Comment: @youngtred. If you try the code above, it sshould work.  You modified the code and theen saying that it is not working

Comment: I tried using `n <- nrow(my.df)` followed by `my.df$time = seq(0, length.out = n, 0.0005)` however the outcome was not as I thought it would be. Not 0, 0.0005, 0.001, 0.0015 etc

Comment: @youngtred. If you didn't specify the `by`, it would think of other argument `seq(0, length.out = n, by = 0.0005)#
 [1] 0.0000 0.0005 0.0010 0.0015 0.0020 0.0025 0.0030 0.0035 0.0040 0.0045`

Comment: @youngtred. Without specifying the argument, it can look for the order of default arguments i.e. `seq(from = 1, to = 1, by = ((to - from)/(length.out - 1)),
    length.out = NULL, along.with = NULL, ...)`

Comment: Have edited, now have correct output. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want the following sequence:

```
seq(0, 0.1, by=0.0005)
```

You may replace the `from` and `to` values to whatever you want via:

```
seq(from, to, by=0.0005)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `seq` by specifying `length.out` parameter as number of rows of dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
df$time <- seq(0, by = 0.0005, length.out = nrow(df))
df

#    a   time
#1   1 0.0000
#2   2 0.0005
#3   3 0.0010
#4   4 0.0015
#5   5 0.0020
#6   6 0.0025
#7   7 0.0030
#8   8 0.0035
#9   9 0.0040
#10 10 0.0045
```